# Contacting Turtlebot Distributor (I Heart Engineering)

Tags: turtlebot, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am having an issue with some of the equipment that my organization purchased through I Heart Engineering. Apparently I Heart Engineering has closed down and I am having a hard time getting in contact with them for warranty and support.

Is anyone else having this issue?
What did you do to get in contact with them?
Or does anyone have any suggestions for me?

The problem was not user error, the devices we ordered and received came with Asus x200 laptops. Those laptops have defective batteries, we didn't know they didn't work because we neglected to test them 6 months ago when we received them for the first time.We took the equipment out last week for a test drive to come and find out the batteries don't work. So now we have about two laptops without batteries that came through I Heart Engineering.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207130/contacting-turtlebot-distributor-(i-heart-engineering)./) by [choog](https://answers.ros.org/users/18787/choog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2015-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Laptop batteries need to be periodically topped up to keep them from falling below their minimum voltage due to self-discharge.

You may be able to recover them by leaving them on a charger for a few days, but don't expect full capacity from them.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [choog](https://answers.ros.org/users/18787/choog/) on 2015-04-15**:
The only problem with that logic is that we had a total of 4 that were in storage for a while and there is only 2 that have this battery issue. I did some research on the model of asus laptop that was shipped to us and other people had lemons. Therefore it leads to a defective conclusion.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-04-15**:
If the laptops themselves are faulty, you may want to contact ASUS directly for a replacement.